# UITableView grabbing touch events from subviews

Tags: objective-c, events, uitableview, touch, subview

I have a UITableView, which loads UIViews into its cells. These UIViews use the -touchesBegan:withEvent: etc methods, which all work fine & let me implement code to move these subviews around in the table. This all works, until I move my finger vertically & start scrolling the table, then the UIViews stop receiving any touch events. If anyone knows how to get around this I'd be very happy! Many thanks.

Answer (score 3):

```
-(void)ViewDidLoad
{
    UITapGestureRecognizer *tapped = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tapped)];
    tapped.numberOfTapsRequired = 2;
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:tapped];   
    [tapped release];
}

-(void)tapped
{
    NSLog(@"TAPPED");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The parent UIScrollView of your UITableView might take over responding to your touch events.

Just [forward](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4223771/touch-forwarding-on-uitableview) the event to your custom subviews.

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event 
{ 
    if ([touches count] == 1) 
    { 
        //Your code here than should return if it reacts to touch

    }
    //forwarding action: 
    [self.nextResponder touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];
}
```

Source: [Touch forwarding on uitableview?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4223771/touch-forwarding-on-uitableview/4223821#4223821)

Comment: Thanks for this, however I still can't stop the table from grabbing the touches events when I start to move my finger vertically (ie, it scrolls the table & doesn't send the event to my subview). I'll keep investigating it & post back if I find out how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Old topic but I was struggling with the same issue (UITableView as a subview to UITableView). Just disable the scrolling for the "parent" UITableView with the scrollEnabled = NO. That will stop the vertical scrolling.